# Is it possible in a optimzation problem the function value converge but the variable does not converge?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we want to optimize $f(x)$, is it possible there exist an algorithm which could make the function $f(x)$ converge to an optimal value but can not make the variable $x$ converge? 
For example: there exist a region $A$ such that any $x\in A$ minimizes $f(x)$, and the algorithm makes $x$ wondering inside $A$. Is this possible? Is there any specific example?

Comment: Pretty much every optimization algorithm will stop once the function values stop changing, so even if the functions has a region like you describe, the algorithm will stop once you reach it

Comment: Agreed. In my experience most convex optimization algorithms will either have some sort of implicit bias towards a particular point in $A$—for example, the analytic center—or they simply terminate when sufficiently close to an optimal point anyway. In the case of a simplex algorithm for LP, you could actually converge to a true optimum in a finite number of iterations, and even if an entire face is optimum, it would not continue once it reaches that optimal value—but there won't necessarily be a guarantee about the particular point obtained.

Comment: What I mean is: If you don't give the algorithm a stopping condition, is it  possible the algorithm will make the variable end up wondering within an "optimal region", which means  the optimal value of the function converges, but the optimal variable does not converge.

Comment: Why would you expect any algorithm to do that? The purpose of an optimization algorithm is to improve the objective value. If, for example, you're within the interior of that region $A$, there is no direction you can move which will improve your objective. So there is no justification for the algorithm to suggest movement.

Comment: The only reason an algorithm would continue to take steps of non-trivial size within $A$ is if you included a stochastic/random component to your search, in order to overcome a potential non-global, local minimum. In a convex optimization context there would be no reason to do that, but in a non-convex optimization setting there might be. So basically—the only time $x$ would "wander" _is if you deliberately made it do that_.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Take Newton's method on the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, on the domain $(0, \infty)$. Take a first estimate $x_0 = 1$, and define
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{\frac{1}{x_n}}{-\frac{1}{x_n^2}} = 2x_n.$$
Inductively, we see $x_n = 2^n$. Note that $f(x_n) = \frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$, the infimal value of the function, but the iterates $x_n$ fail to converge.

Comment: This actually isn't the scenario described by the OP. In this case, the optimal value is never attained. The OP's scenario has the optimal value attained over a non-empty, non-singleton set.

Comment: @MichaelGrant What if we extend the above $f$ by forcing $f(0) = 0$? Then the minimal value of the function is attained. The optimal value is attained uniquely by the function, yet the above algorithm fails to converge.

Comment: You've broken convexity that way. But to be fair the poster didn't explicitly say $f$ was convex.

Comment: @MichaelGrant What convexity?

Comment: I was assuming convexity by virtue of the fact the OP tagged it that way. But sure, if you throw out convexity, all bets are off.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Also, to be fair, they never explicitly said this optimal value was achieved by the function either.

Comment: They did indeed: "there exist a region $A$ such that any $x\in A$ minimizes $f(x)"... it's reasonable to assume $A$ is intended to be non-empty, especially since s/he talks about $x$ "wandering inside $A$".

Comment: @MichaelGrant I read that as an "e.g.", not an "i.e.".

Comment: Forget what I said in that comment I deleted :-)